# Execute two functions concurrently using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I currently have a setup where I open a subprocess and I have to read both `stdout` and `stderr` **at the same time**, so after invoking the subprocess I spawn a new thread for `stdout` and just handle `stderr` in the main thread.

```
# imports
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread


def handle_stdout(stdout):
    # ... do something with stdout,
    # not relevant to the question
    pass


def my_fn():
    proc = Popen([...], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    Thread(target=lambda: handle_stdout(proc.stdout)).start()
    # ... handle stderr
    print(proc.stderr.read())
    proc.wait()
    proc.kill()

my_fn()
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same thing using asyncio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread-free `asyncio` version of your code might look something like this:

```
import asyncio
import asyncio.subprocess

async def handle_stdout(stdout):
    while True:
        line = await stdout.readline()  # Possibly adding .decode() to get str
        if not line:
            break
    # In 3.8 four lines above can be replaced with just:
    # while line := await stdout.readline():  # Yay walrus operator!
        # ... do stuff with line ...

async def my_fn():
    # Note: No list wrapping on command line arguments; all positional arguments are part of the command
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(..., stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_task = asyncio.create_task(handle_stdout(proc.stdout))
    # ... handle stderr
    print(await proc.stderr.read())
    await stdout_task
    await proc.wait()

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(my_fn())
```

The APIs are a little different, async functions are actually called when you make tasks from them (where threads must take uncalled functions), and you need to be careful to `await` all async actions taken, but it's not *that* different. The main issue is `async`'s viral nature; since you can only `await` in an `async` function, it's hard to call async code from non-async code (the other way around works fine, as long as the non-async code doesn't block for any reason). It makes async code bases largely incompatible with non-`async` stuff, and makes converting piecemeal nearly impossible, but for brand new code, it works fine.

Comment: I think it's `await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()`, works as intended though

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev: Yeah, this was whipped up without testing, you'd want the `await`.